# merge two crossreference tables?

Tags: database, database-design, cross-reference

I have three tables with many-to-many relationships:
**profile**, **role** and **type**

Then, I have two cross-reference tables:

```
profile_role:
  role_id    : int
  profile_id : int

profile_type:
  profile_id : int
  type_id    : int
```

The common external id in both tables is **profile_id**.
My idea is that I create a table that contains the three external ids:

```
profile_role_type:
  role_id    : int
  profile_id : int
  type_id    : int
```

My question : is the two designs are equivalent (no data loss or redundancy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`profile_role_type` would only be a valid replacement if there is *exactly* one row in `profile_role` with the same `profile_id` for every row in `profile_type`.

That's  the long and the short of it.